# Data retrieval by key is slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table with a huge number of rows. I stored a few ids from that table in another table, hoping that I will be able to retrieve them faster, since I have their key. However, my code is not any faster, why is that?

```
selectedexpression = learnedexpressions.Where(e => e.ID == nextexpression.foreignExpressionsId).First();
```

So, learnedexpressions has a lot of records, but I expect to get the right one quickly, because I search for it by it's key.

The ID field is set "identity".

Comment: Is this query hitting the database? Or is your list already loaded into memory?

Comment: You do have an index over ID on `learnedexpressions`, right?

Comment: @Ann L. I have not created one... How to do that? (or how do I see if I have?)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It's hitting the database I guess (first time I use anything from that table)